# Dynamic Nested folder pages in nuxt 3

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I want a different data, and on the pages `slug` and `section` should be dynamic.[Enter image description here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibXCl.png)

I want to achieve this routing structure which I provide in the image there is folder called.

community/[...slug]/

```
               index.vue
               
               [section]
                       
                        index.vue
```

when opened the page like localhost:3000/community/grandview-terrace It working fine

but when i open page like ocalhost:3000/community/grandview-terrace/dinner It's open the same previous page view.

Comment: Can you add more details on your question? It's unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: If you need more complex routes, i'd recommend creating your own router file, where you can specify your routes directly. You can find how to do that in Nuxt3 documentation: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/custom-routing

Comment: HI @ReaganM I just updated my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pages structure should be like this.
[image]

When working with nested dynamic pages, it is safer to create a dynamic Nuxt page and a dynamic folder. e.g. in your case, you want the `slug` to be dynamic, so you create a vue file called `[slug].vue` and inside this file is the [NuxtPage](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/components/nuxt-page#nuxtpage)

`slug.vue`

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtPage />
  </div>
</template>
```

After that, create a dynamic `slug` folder like this `[slug]` and add an `index.vue` inside that folder, and inside that `index.vue` file will be the content of your dynamic `slug` route.

Also, this [documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/pages#nested-routes) will help you understand how nested pages works

`index.vue` content e.g

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      Dynamic Slug page
      <pre>{{ $route.params }}</pre>
    </div>
    <NuxtLink to="/">Back to Home page</NuxtLink>
  </div>
</template>
```

A working example based on your question can be found here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-ea4ynz?file=pages%2Findex.vue

**NOTE:** Always restart Nuxt when you create a new page/pages

See also
[NuxtJS nested routes with param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75667222/nuxtjs-nested-routes-with-param/75668752#75668752)

Comment: If anyone here is looking for a tutorial here is the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ccqIAvriVVo